# Conditional formatting on BootstrapVue <b-form-select>?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a `<b-form-input>` in my vue component. I have the `:options` set to an array of email addresses.

This is the list of email addresses that the user can start a chat with. The method i use to get these email addresses, i can't really stop the `<b-input-select>` from having the currently logged in users email address in it.

This is a problem because obviously a user shouldn't be able to start a chat with themself.

Is there a way to conditionally render these `:option`s based on if they're not equal to the email address of the currently signed in user?

The tag i currently have is this:

```
<b-form-select :options="usersNotChatting" v-model="newChat.participants[1].userEmail"></b-form-select>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `computed` property for filtering option data.

```
computed:{
    getoption(){
      let filtered_option = this.mail_list.filter(function(item){
        return item.value!='Test2@gmail.com' // currently signed user email
      })
      return filtered_option;
    }
  }

<b-form-select id="exampleInput3"
                      :options="getoption"
                      required
                      v-model="newChat.participants[1].userEmail">
        </b-form-select>
```